# Firefox. Stop response if it takes too much time

Tags: firefox, selenium

I'm using Selenium WebDriver 2.31.2.0 and FireFox 19.0.2. In my tests some pages takes too much time to load all resources (pictures). Pictures are loaded after all dom elements required for tests are created. So I need some mechanism to prevent selenium wait for complete page load. I tried to use

```
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
```

but tests became too unstable. So my question: is there any options in firefox config to end up long responses or at least return HTTP error if response takes more than specified timeout.

Comment: Which language are you programming on? I guess the general idea will be to grab an element which will be sufficient for your test purposes. You can complete remove the page load and set your own time limit using a simple loop which will try to locate specific element for certain time then set a var to fail when that time expires..

Comment: I'm using c#. Thank you for you answer, but currently I just wrapping "dangerous places" like _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl() into try catch block and catch WebDriverTimeoutException, by the time it raise, all necessary elements are available on page.